# Counter not incrementing when defining crefname with cleveref and algpseudocode

Tags: hyperref, counters, algorithms, labels, cleveref

I am renaming the "line" label for lines in the `algorithmic` environment, since I am using the default label for `lstlisting` environment. As soon as I add define `\crefname` for it, the counter does not increase.

It's a simple problem, so an example will illustrate it best.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{opC}{operation}{operations}
\Crefname{opC}{Operation}{Operations}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[bt]
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State First line
            \label[opC]{line:1}
            \State Second line
            \label[opC]{line:2}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
Refer here to \cref{line:1} and to \cref{line:2}. 
These two work just fine: \cref{line:4} and \cref{line:3}.
    \begin{algorithm}[bt]
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State Another first line
            \label{line:3}
            \State Another second line
            \label{line:4}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled example]

I tried with `\newcounter{opC}` and `\crefalias{opC}{line}` to no avail.

Incidentally, `\ref` returns numbers as it should, as shown for the second algorithm. Also, the `hyperref` links point to the right location (though hard to check in this MWE), so only the actual label is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the `cleveref` package documentation further, I stumbled across a warning in section *14.1 Non-bugs*. Even though I did not use `\label` in an optional argument to another command (as the third bullet suggests), it seems that it should be enclosed with curly braces in order to work properly.

Correcting `\label[opC]{line:1}` into `{\label[opC]{line:1}}` in the example above fixes the problem.